# KML files to IPad securely? Altitude and shape problems in Google Earth

Tags: shapefile, web-mapping

Does anyone know any options for maintaining privacy of the files and getting them onto iPad using Google Earth?

Using Google account to link to Google Earth, privacy settings in Google my maps are Public and Unlisted (still public if you know the URL), no security of files here.

Using MapBox, this requires use of TileMill and the privacy settings are the same public and unlisted (which are public if you guess the URL), support is very limited for KML/KMZ this way in any case.

Using DropBox a cloud based option as is Sugar Sync, this is password protected and files open in Google Earth, how ever there is a problem with polygon/shape data when clicked on does not display the info bubble.

Does anyone know how I would get them onto the iPad securely?

And does anyone know whether there is a work around for the shape/polygon data displaying in google earth on iOS? what would happen if I changed the Altitude mode??

Comment: You can email the kml file to your account (ie gmail) login to your email on the ipad then open the attached file in google earth on the ipad.

Comment: You do know Google parses the KML though their servers right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822649/how-long-does-google-maps-cache-kml-files

Comment: Do you want to make the file available to users, or just for yourself? Do you trust the users?